# return value from computed properties callback did not update templates

Tags: ember.js

Sorry for the long title. Its quite hard to put into words.
Ember version: 1.2.0

here goes:

My components:

```
App.AutocompleteComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
searchResults: function() {
                   var returnValue
                   var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
                   service.getPlacePredictions({options},callback);

                   function callback(results){
                      returnValue = results;
                   }


                    return returnValue;
                   }.property('searchText')
```

My Templates:

```
{{input type="text" value=searchText placeholder="Search..."}}
<ul >
   {{#each itemResults}}
     <li>{{this.name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When i debug using ember chrome debug tool, i can see the component holding the searchResults values correctly. But it is not being updated accordingly in the template.

Any ideas?

if this way of handling/using computed property is not suggested, can suggest any other ways?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to debounce this (and I don't know what options is, is it a global var?).  And the template is itemResults instead of searchResults. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce

```
  watchSearchResults: function() {
     var self = this;
     var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

     var callback= function(results){
         self.set('searchResults', results);
     }
     service.getPlacePredictions({options},callback);
  }.observes('searchText')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kingpin2k for your response,

I have found other way of dealing with returns that obviously didn't work on callbacks and since computed property which in a way requires 'returns' making it not feasible on this use case.

Instead i have opt to using Observers.

By the way, this code is was meant to be dealing with auto complete.

here is the final code:

```
WebClient.AutocompleteFromComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
 searchTextChanged: Em.observer('searchText',function(){ 

var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

            service.getPlacePredictions({
                input: this.get('searchText'),
                types: ['(regions)'],
                componentRestrictions: {
                    country: 'my'
                }
            }, function(predictions, status) {
                //Start callback function
                if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    alert(status);
                    return;
                }
                for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
                    console.log(prediction.description);
                    mapItem = {};
                    mapItem.name = prediction.description;
                    mapItem.type = 'map'
                    mapItem.reference = prediction.reference;
                    itemResults.push(mapItem);


                }
                //console.log(itemResults)
                self.set('itemResults', itemResults)

            });
})
```

The template code is still the same.